# Who catch exception, arise in close method?(try-with-resources)

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

interface `AutoClosable` has following method declaration:

```
void close()  throws Exception
```

Thus we see that method close can throws Exception.

When I write code try-with resources it is looks like this:

```
private static void printFileJava7() throws IOException {

    try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.txt")) {

        int data = input.read();
        while(data != -1){
            System.out.print((char) data);
            data = input.read();
        }
    }
}
```

At this code is absent Exception handling.

I don't understand what happens if close method throws exception.

Answer (score 2):

Java catches and suppresses exceptions thrown by the close method in a try-with-resources block.

You can read more about this here, see in particular the paragraph after the second code sample. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I think this is what the OP is looking for. +1. I add a quote from the document you are linking, so that if the OP wants to retrieve the suppressed exception knows how to do: `You can retrieve these suppressed exceptions by calling the Throwable.getSuppressed method from the exception thrown by the try block.`

Answer (score 0):

The key to this particular scenario is the "supressed exception".

> "Whenever an exception is thrown within the body, and then followed
>   by an exception thrown by the try-with-resources statement, only the
>   exception thrown in the body of the try is eligible to be caught by
>   the exception handling code. All other exceptions are considered supressed exceptions"

A concept that is new with Java 7.SO you will get the same output as when only the printfileJava7 class throws an exception, since the CloseException thrown by the close() method would be suppressed.

Please refer to [When two exceptions are thrown by the try-with-resources construct](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/OCPJP-OCAJP-Java-7-Suppressed-Exceptions-Try-With-Resources) link.Which have taken exact scenario what You have asked

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `close()` method defined in `AutoClosable` throws exception. However other interface named `Closable` that extends `AutoClosable` redefines this method as following:

`void close() throws IOException`

All IO related classes implement `Closable`, so their `close()` method throws `IOException`. But your method throws it too, so in your code no-one catches this exception. As always it will be caught by upper layer of your application or by JVM itself if no-one catches it before.

Comment: but if will catch IOException inside my method? Will I catch Exceptions throws inside cloase method?

Answer (score 0):

From the [jls about Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2)

> When interfaces are involved, more than one method declaration may be overridden by a single overriding declaration. In this case, the overriding declaration must have a throws clause that is compatible with all the overridden declarations (§9.4.1).

So when you have something like

```
static class AC implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("btooom!");
    }
    public void ac() {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try(AC ac = new AC()) {
        ac.ac();
    }
}
```

then you are forded to either add a catch clause to the surrounding try block or add a throws declaration.

In the case of [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and to apply what the jsl states, the [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)'s close method is [overriden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1) from [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)'s, hence you only have to catch an [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) or add it to throws clause.

Further the javadocs of [AutoCloseable#close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--) states

> While this interface method is declared to throw Exception, implementers are strongly encouraged to declare concrete implementations of the close method to throw more specific exceptions, or to throw no exception at all if the close operation cannot fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a catch block followed by try in the method printFileJava7(). If you don't want to catch it here, you need handle it in the method which calls the method printFileJava7(). We have to catch in one of the layers otherwise it will be propagated back to the calling client.